# ¿Cómo interpretar las gráficas de la función pcr del paquete qualityTools en R?

Tags: r

Para una variable referente al diámetro interior de una pieza (de un dataframe dado), aplicamos la función pcr para analizar la capacidad de un proceso con límite inferior 35.02 y limite superior 35.18.
Mi problema es que al obtener las gráficas, no sé interpretar bien los valores de la fracción esperada de piezas defectuosas (en piezas por millón), no sé cuándo he de decir que están por encima o por debajo del margen inferior o superior.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tu pregunta parece interesante pero lamentablemente no es tema de programación, ¿has probado intentar hacerla en hacerla en https://stats.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque no parece ser consistente con la temática del sitio.

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque no parece ser consistente con la temática del sitio.